# How to populate table with Firebase data?

Tags: angularjs

I have in Realtime + Angular, the following structure:

[image]

I have a working backend and returning all items of the node, performing some tests, managed.

Code do request data:

[image]

Retrieve JSON in console with (click):

```
console.log('RESULTADO QUERY: ', resultado)
```

[image]

Data converted to an array (one more test):

```
const usersJson: any[] = Array.of(snapshot.val())
console.log('ARRAYS: ', usersJson)
```

[image]

Now my problem starts, how can I populate an HTML table with some of the data obtained? I tried to use interpolation, `ng-repeat`, `ngFor`, `ngTemplate` to no avail.

Could you guide me on the best way?

Tks!

Comment: Did you assign the data to a $scope variable? Some of your html and js code would be helpful

Comment: Hello! I am using Angular 8, I believe the scopes are only used in the old Angular. But answering your question, I did not use scope for the above reason.

Comment: I see. I would provide any of the angular and html code that pertains to your issue.